# Characteristic of old SLA/NiCd batteries

Tags: batteries, nicd-battery

I need service an old HVAC equipment (manufactured 1998) backuped using **6x2V SLA 5000mA Cyclone** cells (http://www.ges.cz/cz/akumulator-oloveny-cyclon-x-cell-5-0ah-GES07600853.html). There is also **3xNiCd AA 600mA**. I plan to replace all these cells because I suppose **17year** old batteries cannot be in good condition.

I measured voltage particular cells and I'm surprised it varies significantly. Some cells have 0.9V (both NiCd and SLA), a few SLAs 2V, one SLA cell even 2.7V. Two NiCds have 1.28V. Measured as I removed from device, no load. When I put in NiCd in charger to make test cycle then charger does not recognize cell.

My question is if is possible that some batteries survived 17year in good condition, i.e. is worth testing piece by piece and replace only cells with low voltage?

What happen that 2V SLA cell provides 2.7V, is it normal feature?

Comment: Even the "good" ones will only have a fraction of  their original capacity and mixing them with new cells is only going to cause early failure and future problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most certainly a mix of (fairly) good and defective cells.  When one cell becomes defective the others can begin to over charge (showing a higher charged voltage, but will eventually become defective).  At that age (and the likely over charging) much better to replace all the cells.